# Get raw keyboard and mouse input data in background

Tags: c, windows, input

I want to get raw keyboard and mouse data in the background, but I also need to know which device it is coming from. I know both things are possible, but I can't find a method where I can read the input in the background and detect which device at the same time

Comment: do you want process of getting raw keyboard and mouse data in the background on your system?

Comment: If you need to read raw input use the [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) API.